# Probability Independence to reduce terms.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Is the following probability reduction correct?

```
p(A,B|C,D) = p(A,B|C), where (A,B) is independent of D
```

Is it because of the following prove:

```
p(A,B|C,D) 
= p(A,B,C,D) / p(C,D)
= p(D)*p(A,B,C) / p(C)*p(D)
= p(A,B,C) / p(C)
= P(A,B|C)
```

If so, then isn't it `(A,B,C) is independent of D` rather than `(A,B) is independent of D`?

Comment: In the second equality you use that $P(A,B,C,D)=P(D)\cdot P(A,B,C)$ which requires that $(A,B,C)$ is independent of $D$, which you haven't assumed.

Comment: but why is `p(A,B|C,D) = p(A,B|C), where (A,B) is independent of D` correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a simple counterexample, throw a fair coin twice, call $C$ the event that the first throw was a head, $D$ the event that the second throw was a head and $A=B$ the event that both throws coincide.

Then $A$ is independent of $D$ while $P(A\mid C,D)=1$ and $P(A\mid C)=\frac12$.

On the other hand, if $D$ is independent of $(A,B,C)$, the proof you suggest is correct and shows indeed that $P(A,B\mid C,D)=P(A,B\mid C)$.

Comment: So does that means the first equation (`p(A,B|C,D) = p(A,B|C), where (A,B) is independent of D`) is incorrect since the independence assumption doesn't include D?

Comment: Which first equation?

Comment: In your example, `A is independent of D while P(A∣C,D)=1 and P(A∣C)=0.5`; you mean that `P(A|C,D) != P(A|C) when A is independent of D`, right?

Comment: Rather I mean that the independence of $A$ and $D$ does not imply that $P(A\mid C,D)=P(A\mid C)$ (but $P(A\mid C,D)=P(A\mid C)$ does hold for *some* independent $A$ and $D$, only, not always).

Comment: why not always?

Comment: Well, say, as shown by the example in my post!

Comment: ah, now i see =) , a counterexample.

Comment: I replied you over there)